# What javascript code am I missing to make my modals open when pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I've reached a stumbling block and cannot figure out what I am missing in my Javascript to allow each modal box to open when the button is clicked.  Right now, the first button works and brings up my photo 1, but the rest do not do anything else except for the hover property.  I've tried to add different classes, containers, and have looked online to see if I can find what my issue is.  I'm sure it is probably something simple that I am just forgetting.

Here is my code pen:

https://codepen.io/benjamin-schneider82/pen/qKbZzg

```js
// Animate smooth scroll

$('#view-work').on('click', function() {
  const images = $('#images').position().top;

  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: images
    },
    900
  );
});

// Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');

// Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');


// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// Listen for open click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);

// Listen for close click
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

// Listen for Outside click
window.addEventListener('click', clickOutside);



// Function to open modal
function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to close modal
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to close modal if outside click
function clickOutside(e) {
  if (e.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="landing-image"></div>
<div id="images">
  <div id="header">
    <h2>My Projects</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt=""></button>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <a href="http://www.developitben.com">
            <h2>Photo One</h2>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, cupiditate.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt=""></button>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <h2>Photo Two</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, cupiditate.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt=""></button>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <h2>Photo Three</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, cupiditate.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt=""></button>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <h2>Photo Four</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolores, cupiditate.</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt=""></button>
    <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
          <h2>Photo Five</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water" alt="">
        </div>
```

Thank you for your time!

Ben

Comment: you have duplicate element IDs, this is invalid HTML. IDs must be unique, otherwise (obviously) they're not an ID! When you run `var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');` how is the code supposed to know which of the 5 possible elements with that ID it's meant to select? BTW by default it will always select the first one, and ignores the others because they, logically, cannot exist.

Comment: same for `modalBtn`. So clicking on your first image works, but none of the others ever will. Use class selectors for this instead of IDs, because they can be applied to multiple elements. And I suggest making your syntax consistent so you always use jQuery syntax for everything (easier and simpler IMHO) or always use native JS syntax for everything. Right now you have an untidy mixture of both.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It takes another set of eyes to point out something that I now see and makes perfect sense.   I'm still in the learning process of jquery and javascript.  If I am understanding correctly, you are referring to the first code I have at the top of the JS and need to make it like the rest of the page?

Comment: the very first part of your example uses jQuery style syntax for defining the "click" event handler. IMO this is simpler to use and clearer to read than the standard JS syntax, and I'd recommend it. But it's your choice.

Comment: I appreciate your help, ADyson.